# How to publish jar to somewhere on internet via gradle task?

Tags: github, gradle, jar, continuous-integration, repository

I have a project set up with CI and gradle building, and I want to add a gradle task to publish a jar somewhere we can access it every time a CI build runs.

I don't even know (or care) what service I would be uploading to; anything works.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider setting a GitHub repository, just for publishing artifacts (what you are building as **[GitHub releases](https://help.github.com/articles/about-releases/)**)

In gradle, you can use:

- [`riiid/gradle-github-plugin`](https://github.com/riiid/gradle-github-plugin)
- or [`ajoberstar/gradle-git`](https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-git)

Answer (score 0):

You can use some kind of artifactory, like sonatype nexus or jfrog artifactory. They are the main building blogs of a good CI architecture.

https://www.jfrog.com/article/continuous-integration-systems/

https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-sonatype

Answer (score 0):

You can publish to [bintray.com](https://bintray.com) (from jfrog).

That will give you a repo you can use like so:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://dl.bintray.com/yourOrg/yourRepo/'
    }
}
```

Then if you get serious, automatic synchronisation on `jcenter()` repository is just a click and approval away.

To upload via gradle task:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.jfrog.bintray' version '1.7.3'
}
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

group 'com.example' //your group ID
version '0.1'       //your version

//required for jcenter
task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

//required for jcenter
task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

artifacts {
    archives jar
    archives sourcesJar //required for jcenter
    archives javadocJar //required for jcenter
}

publishing {
    publications {
        MyPublication(MavenPublication) {
            groupId group
            artifactId 'Base58'
            version project.version
            //again, sources and javadoc required for jcenter
            artifact("$buildDir/libs/projectName-${project.version}-sources.jar") {
                classifier = 'sources'
            }
            artifact("$buildDir/libs/projectName-${project.version}-javadoc.jar") {
                classifier = 'javadoc'
            }
            artifact("$buildDir/libs/projectName-${project.version}.jar")
        }
    }
}

// To upload a new version
// ./gradlew clean
// ./gradlew build bintrayUpload -Puser=user -Pkey=APIKEY
bintray {
    user = project.ext.properties.user
    key = project.ext.properties.key
    publications = ['MyPublication']
    pkg {
        repo = 'YourBinTrayRepo'
        name = 'YourBinTrayProjectName'
        userOrg = 'YourBinTrayOrganizationIfApplicable'
        licenses = //any licences applicable
        vcsUrl = 'URL to source'
        version project.version
    }
}
```

So to upload:

```
./gradlew clean
./gradlew build bintrayUpload -Puser=user -Pkey=APIKEY
```

Then jump on bintray to hit publish.